# CancellationTokenSource cancelling more then expected

Tags: c#, task

Basically i am running a programm that executes a method that is repeated several times (for example 7 times), but i need an option to cancel the CURRENTLY run one of it, but still allow new ones to start.

My issue is that the programm ends as soon as i hit the cancel button. So i seem to be missing something.

Main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    taskUbung = Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
    {
        await doSomething();
    }, cts.Token);
}
```

Button:

```
 private void buttonSkipUbung_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    cts.Cancel();
 }
```

So if i am hitting the button on the 3rd round of doSomething(), the remaining 4 will never execute.
What do i have to change for my desired behavior? I could just use some booleans and return in doSomething(), but i figured this would be cleaner and more responsive, if it works that is.

Comment: I do not really get your code. If you are starting 7 asynchronous tasks, they would run parallel, that is concept of the whole thing . So you cannot cancel the "current" one, because there is no current one, all of them are.

Comment: Isn't that what await is for? Wait untill doSomething() is done before starting it a second time?

Comment: Since the `await` command is inside the asynchronous task, the task will wait for something, not the main thread which launched the task. So simply put, all 7 tasks will wait for `doSomething()` to finish (which code you did not show us).

Comment: Side note: using `Task.Factory.StartNew(Func<Task>)` without unwrapping the returned task (or double-`await`ing it) is a recipe for disaster. Pay attention to the return type of your `StartNew` (it will be `Task<Task>`). `Task.Run` has overloads which are specifically tailored to `Func<Task>` and `Func<Task<T>>` inputs - use those whenever possible.

Comment: Hmm, figured that it was not THAT easy. Guess ill do some more research on Tasks and just use the boolean "isSkipped" way for now. Working for my programm, just feels like bad coding :/

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense. You're creating 7 CancellationTokenSource, and cancelling the last one. Are you sure it's what you want to do?

Comment: If i was sure about what i do, i would not be sitting here and asking a question, right? I implemented that line in the loop because i thought the Tasks where "started canceled" and that this was my issue. Obviously that was wrong and that line does not help or belong at that spot. Starting a new Task, only after the last is finished / canceled is what i really want. And i don't want the loop to go on untill a Task is finished either, so i put await.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the tokens you are creating in some kind of list. Otherwise you only remember the last one and call cancel only on that one